# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices men2n

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting this error How can I solve this problem

```
def fprop(self, input_data, target_data):
    tmp = [(t, i) for i, t in enumerate(target_data)]
    z = zip(*tmp)  # unzipping trick !
    cost = np.sum(np.log(input_data[z]))
    if self.size_average:
        cost /= input_data.shape[1]
```

Error

```
cost = np.sum(np.log(input_data[z]))
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Exactly what are you aiming to do here? Can you first specify *what* you want to do, instead of *how* you want to do this?

Comment: I am just trying to run a bunch of code then getting this error and Error line show me there is a problem with this piece of code in my file

Comment: error says you use wrong index - it means `z` in `input_data[z]`. So first use `print(z)` to see what you have in variable, next decide what you tried do with `z` and then describe all this in question (not in comment).

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us something about the code and data.  Is it something you wrote or is someone else's?  Is it new, or did it work before, may be in some other context?  What are:

```
input_data, target_data
```

But let's make a reasonable guess, and explore the code step by step (this is something you should have done yourself):

```
In [485]: alist = [1,3,0,2]                                                                                  
In [486]: tmp = [(t,i) for i,t in enumerate(alist)]                                                          
In [487]: tmp                                                                                                
Out[487]: [(1, 0), (3, 1), (0, 2), (2, 3)]
In [488]: z = zip(*tmp)                                                                                      
In [489]: z                                                                                                  
Out[489]: <zip at 0x7ff381d50188>
```

In Python 3, `zip` produces a `zip` object, a generator.  That clearly can't be an index for anything.

We can turn it into a list, which is what Python2 would have done:

```
In [490]: list(z)                                                                                            
Out[490]: [(1, 3, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2, 3)]
```

But that list of tuples is marginally good:

```
In [491]: x = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)                                                                     
In [492]: x[_490]                                                                                            
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use `arr[tuple(seq)]` instead of `arr[seq]`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, `arr[np.array(seq)]`, which will result either in an error or a different result.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[492]: array([ 4, 13,  2, 11])
```

If we turn that into a tuple of tuples, `numpy` works without the warning:

```
In [493]: x[tuple(_490)]                                                                                     
Out[493]: array([ 4, 13,  2, 11])
```

This is the same as using `alist` to pick one value per column:

```
In [494]: x[alist, np.arange(4)]                                                                             
Out[494]: array([ 4, 13,  2, 11])

In [495]: x                                                                                                  
Out[495]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

I should have expanded the `zip` with `tuple` initially:

```
In [502]: x[tuple(zip(*tmp))]                                                                                
Out[502]: array([ 4, 13,  2, 11])
```

Having worked through this, I now suspect this code originally worked for Python2.